# Android MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648

Tags: android, video-streaming

I've working android camera video streaming for a while. I tried libstreaming package first, but had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110287/get-error-camera-already-in-use-when-usb-debugging-on-my-nexus-5-with-libstreami) issue. So I followed the Google Camera sample [code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) to write my own class. But after I passing a `ParcelFileDescriptor` to `mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile`, I get this error:

```
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sharedcameraandroid, PID: 14868
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
at MainActivity.startRecordingVideo(MainActivity.java:268)
at MainActivity.setUpMediaRecorder(MainActivity.java:257)
```

So I checked online and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731785/android-mediarecorder-start-failed-2147483648-on-2-3-3) (change outputformat to 3GPP),  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960117/mediarecorder-start-failed) to `add Thread.sleep` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990816/mediarecorder-issue-on-android-lollipop). But all of them didnt work. So I come to ask if anyone knows how to fix the issue.

Here is my code:

```
private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    final Activity activity = mActivity;
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }

    ParcelFileDescriptor[] parcelFileDescriptors = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
    mParcelRead = new ParcelFileDescriptor(parcelFileDescriptors[0]);
    mParcelWrite  = new ParcelFileDescriptor(parcelFileDescriptors[1]);

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
//        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile((new File(mActivity.getExternalFilesDir(null), "video.mp4")).getAbsolutePath());
//        Log.d(TAG, (new File(mActivity.getExternalFilesDir(null), "video.mp4")).getAbsolutePath());
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mParcelWrite.getFileDescriptor());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    // mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    startRecordingVideo();
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598299/how-to-record-video-on-android-into-stream

    InputStream is = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(mParcelRead);
    RtspClient client = new RtspClient(is, releaseSampleFile());
    client.startStream();
}
```

If I change the `mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mParcelWrite.getFileDescriptor());` with the commented lines, everything is fine.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do u get solution for this.. i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Sadly, no... I used another streaming package instead

Comment: can u please tell us about other streaming package.  We were able to use libstreaming  library with MEDIA CODEC API 2 with less video quality

Answer (score 1):

Recently i got stuck in this problem in my project. so tried changing some of the parameters. and luckily when i changed the OutputFormat to MPEG_2_TS it worked.

So what's i am saying is change the outputformat to MPEG_2_TS. It worked for me. So lets hope it works for you.